# If-Ifelse logic with partly repeating condition

Tags: if-statement, spss-modeler

```
I1 S1 I2 S2 I3 S3 I4 S4 I5 S5 I6 S6 ACTUAL WANTED

10 1  10  2  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0    3      3

10 1  10  2  10 3  0  0   0  0  0  0    3      6

10 1  10  2  10 3  10 4   0  0  0  0    3      10
```

`if I1=I2 then (S1+S2)
elseif I1=I2=I3 then (S1+S2+S3)
elseif I1=I2=I3=I4 then (S1+S2+S3+S4)
else "" 
endif`
the code don't consider the other condition when the first is verified, i don't know how to build a loop and consider all condition. 
Thank you very much for your help i hope is clear now , and you're write is spss modeler

Answer (score 0):

Your first logical condition covers all cases where `I1=I2`, including cases where `I1=I2=I3` or `I1=I2=I3=I4`.  So **ALL** these cases will get the result `(S1+S2)` and none of them are left for the `elseif`.
In order to give special treatment for the `I1=I2=I3=I4` cases is to treat them FIRST, then what's left are the cases where `I1=I2=I3` or `I1=I2` but not `I1=I2=I3=I4`. Now you do the same thing with the `I1=I2=I3` cases. Once you've treated them, you are left with the rest of the `I1=I2` cases.

So I know nothing about SPSS modeler language, but based on the code you've posted, your command should look like this:

```
if I1=I2=I3=I4 then (S1+S2+S3+S4)
elseif I1=I2=I3 then (S1+S2+S3)
elseif I1=I2 then (S1+S2)
else ""
```